# Django optimize for loop in method

Tags: python, django

I wrote the method to check one attribute and return False if there is an artist with selling=False, and True otherwise.

```
def check_selling(track, excludes):
    """
    Returns True if all track's artists are allowed for selling. False otherwise
    """
    for artist in track.artists.all():
            if not artist.selling:
                excludes.append(track.pk)
                return False
    return True
```

How can i minimize this?

I tried:

```
def check_selling(track, excludes):
    res = excludes.append(track.pk) if not [artist.selling for artist in track.artists.all()] else True
    return res or False
```

But [False] or [True] resulting in list comprehension [artist.selling for artist in track.artists.all()] always gives True...

Comment: What is "artist.selling" ? can it be null or empty string?

Comment: boolean field, default=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Queries!
See [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

```
def check_selling(track, excludes):
    """
    Returns True if all track's artists are allowed for selling. False otherwise
    """
    if track.artists.filter(selling=False).exists(): #If "selling" is a boolean
        excludes.append(track)
        return False
    return True
```

Just one query

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

**New in version 2.5.**

```
def check_selling(track, excludes):
    """
    Returns True if all track's artists are allowed for selling. False otherwise
    """
    if all( [artist.selling for artist in track.artists.all()] ):
        return True
    excludes.append(track.pk)
    return False
```

Comment: I do recommend you look at `Sylvain Leroux`'s answer.

Comment: Yes, You are making one query for artist in track

Answer (score 2):

*premature optimization is the root of all evil* -- Donald Knuth

... but, it is no question of *optimization* here. But of *doing right*.

It is highly inefficient to retrieve *all* records just to count those having a given attribute. You could do much better at SQL level:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist WHERE SELLING != false
```

That statement will directly return the *number* of artist *not* selling. Not only this will reduce traffic between the RDBMS and your application -- but in some cases, the RDBMS will be able to "optimize" this statement, either by using an index (if you have one on "selling") and/or its cache. Depending your BD backend, the syntax may vary. The good new is that Django has support for such query using [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count). Something like that:

```
artist.objects.filter(selling!=false).count()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the answer with the use of related manager is more appreciated. But i see your way, it's what i need.